# Verifying Azure blob storage connections are secured

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Some of my `Azure blob storage` have `Secure transfer required` set to `disabled`.
I want to change it to `Enabled`, but I first want to check there are no connections using `HTTP` to make sure nothing breaks. Where can I see the logs/history of the inbound connections types (HTTP/S)?

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieve, but maybe you need to do some custom filter.

First, the log analysis of storage will not log these things.

You need to send logs to `Log Analytics workspace`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then you can find the connections types in the Log Analytics workspace.